# Is there a single command to download binary files from an HTTP server to linux/solaris and install the binary subsequently?

Tags: linux, wget, binaryfiles, solaris-10

I want to automate a process of downloading a binary file from a server (HTTP) and then install it on either Solaris or Linux servers.

I use wget command followed by executing the binary file as root user.

Can we combine these two steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put both commands into a single script that gets executed by root

Comment: Thanks :-) this is the simplest of all, indeed!

Answer (score 1):

You can do

`wget url | command-to-install`

However, if this is a tar folder and you know how to install, you can write a shell script to do it. e.g

```
wget url

tar xvzf archive 
./configure
make
make install
```

and run it as root e.g `sudo ./installscript.sh`